# How to create 10.5'' or 8.0'' tablet in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am making an android application that supports the tablet of 10.1' and Nexus 7 but my client have an 8 inch samsung tablet.

So I want to test my layout in emulator but it have only 7 inch or 10.1' tablet. so how can i test my layout on 8'(Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0) and 10.5'(Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5 LTE) of tablet that any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 5 Question till date and zero accepted answer, Please accept answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to create Custom Device in Device Manager

1. Open **AVD Manager** from Eclipse/ ADT, you will see window like below, Click on "**New Device**"
   [image: AVD window]
2. Then Specify other details majorly "**Screen Size**", "**Resolution**" and "**dpi**".
   After Providing necessary Fields  click on "**Create Device**", **Voila!**
   [image: new device screen]